# PHP Slim Routing with PHPBB

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have Slim 3 routing all my REST requests manually.

My `public_html` `.htaccess` file looks like this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.come/$1 [R=301,L]

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    #RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule . index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

In `index.php` I create a new Slim app

`$app = new \Slim\App($settings);`

And handle all page requests manually

```
$app->get('/contact', function(Request $request, Response $response) use ($user) {
    // render contact.php
});
```

I have just uploaded `phpBB` folder to `public_html/phpBB3`. It comes with its own `.htaccess` file, and I am wondering how to set up Slim or my `public_html` `.htaccess` file to let requests to `www.example.com/phpbb3` to be handled by `phpBB3`

Answer (score 0):

your slim app will already allow this as your public/.htaccess file doesn't route url's that match an existing directory through the app. So just going to http://www.example.com/phpbb3/ will allow phpbb to handle everything from then on in